# Сделать так, чтобы роутер не выдавал 404 страницу Github Pages

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Моё приложение, написанное на vue находится на Github Pages. У меня есть роутер

```typescript
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from "vue-router";
import Index from "../components/screens/Index.vue";
import NoMeta from "../components/screens/NoMeta.vue";

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {name: "index", path: "/", component: Index},
        {name: "noMeta", path: "/nometa", component: NoMeta}
    ],
})

export default router;
```

Но при попытке обратиться на страницу /nometa выдаёт ошибку 404. Что делать?

Comment: как предположение... `name: "noMeta"` а вы обращаетесь как `/nometa`.. JS регистрозависимый.. но конкретно в вашем случае у меня только предположение)

Comment: name это не путь к странице, путь указывается в path

Answer (score 0):

Просто в качестве строкового аргумента для `createWebHistory()` добавьте название репозитория, например 'myrepo':

```js
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from "vue-router";
import Index from "../components/screens/Index.vue";
import NoMeta from "../components/screens/NoMeta.vue";

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory('/myrepo'),
    routes: [
        {name: "index", path: "/", component: Index},
        {name: "noMeta", path: "/nometa", component: NoMeta}
    ],
})

export default router;
```